# How login roundcube by php script?

Tags: php, roundcube

How can login roubdcube by php script?

There is a script http://blog.philippheckel.com/2008/05/16/roundcube-login-via-php-script/ but it does not support host (imap server)
We need to set host (imap server) something similar to login($username, $password,$host)

Answer (score 0):

Logging in to a remote host is not possible, because Roundcube must set a cookie in the client's browser to stay signed in. The above mentioned script passes the cookies on to the browser. Without the cookie, the user will not be logged in successfully even though the credentials might be right.